# Dataframe conditional drop duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From this sample of my dataset, I need to drop duplicate rows that have that have same values in all columns except for "parent_station". The duplicate row that will be removed has to be the one with NaN in "parent_station" column and keep the row that has "parent_station" value different than NaN.
In this example, the row that needs to be removed is the 4th row, with index of 7789.
How can I do this ? I have not yet been able to figure out how.

```
           stop_id         stop_name                    parent_station              trip_id                 arrival_time   departure_time     stop_sequence   route_id      trip_headsign
7022       87413385        Gare de Yvetot               StopArea:OCE87413385        OCESN003100F140147152   05:49:00       05:50:00           2.0             OCE1506035    3100.0
3518       87411017        Gare de Rouen-Rive-Droite    StopArea:OCE87411017        OCESN003100F140147152   06:12:00       06:15:00           3.0             OCE1506035    3100.0
8040       87413013        Gare de Le Havre             StopArea:OCE87413013        OCESN003100F140147152   05:20:00       05:20:00           0.0             OCE1506035    3100.0
7789       87413013        Gare de Le Havre             NaN                         OCESN003100F140147152   05:20:00       05:20:00           0.0             OCE1506035    3100.0
7197       87413344        Gare de Bréauté-Beuzeville   NaN                         OCESN003100F140147152   05:35:00       05:36:00           1.0             OCE1506035    3100.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
out = df[~df.drop('parent_station', axis=1).duplicated(keep=False) | pd.notna(df['parent_station'])]
```

Output:

```
        stop_id                   stop_name        parent_station  \
index                                                               
7022   87413385              Gare de Yvetot  StopArea:OCE87413385   
3518   87411017   Gare de Rouen-Rive-Droite  StopArea:OCE87411017   
8040   87413013            Gare de Le Havre  StopArea:OCE87413013   
7197   87413344  Gare de Bréauté-Beuzeville                   NaN   

                     trip_id arrival_time departure_time  stop_sequence  \
index                                                                     
7022   OCESN003100F140147152     05:49:00       05:50:00            2.0   
3518   OCESN003100F140147152     06:12:00       06:15:00            3.0   
8040   OCESN003100F140147152     05:20:00       05:20:00            0.0   
7197   OCESN003100F140147152     05:35:00       05:36:00            1.0   

         route_id  trip_headsign  
index                             
7022   OCE1506035         3100.0  
3518   OCE1506035         3100.0  
8040   OCE1506035         3100.0  
7197   OCE1506035         3100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop_duplicates`:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'parent_station']
out = df[~(df.duplicated(cols, keep=False) & df['parent_station'].isna())]
print(out)

# Output
       stop_id                   stop_name        parent_station                trip_id arrival_time departure_time  stop_sequence    route_id  trip_headsign
7022  87413385              Gare de Yvetot  StopArea:OCE87413385  OCESN003100F140147152     05:49:00       05:50:00            2.0  OCE1506035         3100.0
3518  87411017   Gare de Rouen-Rive-Droite  StopArea:OCE87411017  OCESN003100F140147152     06:12:00       06:15:00            3.0  OCE1506035         3100.0
8040  87413013            Gare de Le Havre  StopArea:OCE87413013  OCESN003100F140147152     05:20:00       05:20:00            0.0  OCE1506035         3100.0
7197  87413344  Gare de Bréauté-Beuzeville                   NaN  OCESN003100F140147152     05:35:00       05:36:00            1.0  OCE1506035         3100.0
```

Comment: If I get the question correctly, that won't solve OPs question. The drop has to be conditional (in your example it works only because the filled value is before the unfilled one).

Answer (score -1):

Even though it's slightly longer than the explanations above.

```
ss = df.columns.drop('parent_station')

keep_rows = df[(df.duplicated(subset=ss, keep=False)) & (~df.parent_station.isna())]
non_duplicates = df[~(df.duplicated(subset=ss, keep=False))]
df = pd.concat([non_duplicates, keep_rows])
```

Here I make a clear distinction between the rows which have no double at all (non_duplicates) and the duplicate rows that you want to keep (keep_rows).

Answer (score -1):

First `sort_values` and then `drop_duplicates`. while sorting you have an option to keep NaN values to first or last places. Default it is 'last'. Similar param named `keep` we have in drop_duplicates.

References: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

```
output_df = df.sort_values(['parent_station'], na_position='last').drop_duplicates(['stop_id', 'stop_name'], keep='first')
```

Answer (score -1):

Very Easy solution! I hope this is what you were looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'stop_id': ['87413385', '87411017', '87413013', '87413013', '87413344'],
                   'stop_name': ['Gare de Yvetot', 'Gare de Rouen-Rive-Droite', 'Gare de Le Havre', 'Gare de Le Havre', 'Gare de Bréauté-Beuzeville'],
                   'parent_station': ['StopArea:OCE87413385', 'StopArea:OCE87411017', 'StopArea:OCE87413013', np.NaN, np.NaN]})
is_duplacted = df.duplicated(subset=['stop_id', 'stop_name'])
is_nan = df['parent_station'].isna()
print(df[~(is_duplacted & is_nan)])


#     stop_id                   stop_name        parent_station
# 0  87413385              Gare de Yvetot  StopArea:OCE87413385
# 1  87411017   Gare de Rouen-Rive-Droite  StopArea:OCE87411017
# 2  87413013            Gare de Le Havre  StopArea:OCE87413013
# 4  87413344  Gare de Bréauté-Beuzeville                   NaN
```